# Probability or expected value of hirings the company will make?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

This is the full question:

> A company is hiring for an open position and has n interviews set up, one
> per day. Each day, if the candidate is better than the current employee, the employee
> is fired and the candidate is hired. Otherwise, the current employee keeps the job.
> What is the expected number of hirings the company will make?

I got the answer of $\frac{1+(n-1)}{2}$. Is this correct? I used the probability of no new hires and all new hires.

Comment: If $n=1$ your formula yields $\frac 12$ which is hard to interpret.  I assume that in the case $n=1$, the firm hires the only person they speak with, yes?  In which case the answer should be $1$.

Comment: I think the answer is actually $1+\frac {n-1}2$.  Is that what you intended to write?  What you wrote simplifies to $\frac n2$ so perhaps you just have a typo.

Comment: Clarification requested.  On day 3, the only way that the new candidate is hired is if this candidate is better than both of the previous candidates.  **Is the chance of this being true** $\displaystyle \frac{1}{3}$?  If so, it seems as if the correct enumeration is $$1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n}.$$  This analysis assumes that on Day-1, the position is open, so the Day-1 candidate is automatically hired.

Comment: @lulu Is there something wrong in the analysis of my previous comment?

Comment: @user2661923  Let's see.  Suppose our candidates are $a<b<c$.  Then $(a,b,c)\mapsto 3$, $(a,c,b)\mapsto 2$, $(b,a,c)\mapsto 2$, $(b,c,a)\mapsto 2$, and both $(c,a,b)$ and $(c,b,a)$ give $1$.  So the expected number is $1\times \frac 26+2\times \frac 36+3\times \frac 16=\frac {11}6$.  So, yes.  You are right.  A naive use of linearity does not work here.

Comment: @lulu The question that I raised at the start of my first comment is still pending.  On day-3, is the chance of the new hire $(1/3)$ or is it $(1/2)$?  $(1/3)$ makes the most sense, and seems to be the only reasonable interpretation in the absence of a specific premise to the contrary.  However, it does seem as is the OP made the opposite assumption, namely that the chance of a Day-3 new hire is  $(1/2)$.

Comment: @user2661923  I think the OP is just reasoning naively.  Given two consecutive candidates, the probability that the second dominates the first is $\frac 12$.  Unfortunately, that's not what determines a hire.  the hires are precisely those which dominate all their predecessors, not just the immediate one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key question is whether the chance on Day-3 of a new hire is $(1/3)$ or $(1/2)$.  $(1/3)$ makes the most sense, in the absence of a specific premise to the contrary, since the Day-3 hire has to be better than both the Day-1 and Day-2 interviewees to get the job.

Based on this, and based on the premise that the Day-1 hire is automatically hired, given that the position starts out open, the enumeration is

$$1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n}.$$

The alternative interpretation, which seems to be the assumption made by the OP (i.e. original poster) is that the expected number of hires is

$$1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2},$$

where the above enumeration has exactly $n$ terms.

Comment: That’s what will happen if you compare candidates by throwing a coin.

Comment: @gnasher729 Agreed.  I wanted to contrast the two interpretations to clarify in the OP's mind, where he went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Take k potential employees. If one of them comes to the interview on day k, they will be hired if they are the best of the employees, otherwise the best of the j employees has already been hired and keeps their job. So the probability that someone is hired on day k is 1/k.

The expected number of people hired within n days is the sum of 1/k over 1<=k<=n.

In practice, someone who does the job will improve doing it. Hire the tenth best candidate, and after some time they will become better than the nine candidates that were initially better. On the other hand, whoever you hire will eventually move to another job or retire, and you start all over.

And in civilised countries your plan doesn’t work at all because you can’t just fire people like that.